# Custom Chrome scrollbar style's height doesn't work

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar

I want define Chrome scrollbar's style by myself, so I use `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo elements like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <p id="inner">
    Sample
    </p>
</div>

#outer::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
}
#outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue;
}
```

I want change the vertical scrollbar's height, but the `height` property seems doesn't work

here is the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/sPctL/

So how can I let the `height` property work?

Answer (score 0):

If I'v got what u mean, use `max-height` or `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an old question, but...

Doesn't the scrollbar height refer to the height of the horizontal scrollbar, not the vertical?

Do you mean the height of the thumb on the vertical scrollbar?  I get the impression that it's not possible.

Someone yell at me if I'm wrong.  :)